# Можно ли для бесплатной версии ORACLE 11 установить EM?

Tags: oracle

Можно ли для бесплатной версии ORACLE 11 установить EM ?

Хочу научится работать с ним. Мне хоть на месяц увидить, что за зверь такой.

Comment: В бесплатной, это которая со всякими ограничениями, типа лимита на размер базы ? С сайта оракла можно полную версию взять, на просто  попробовать они не особо возражают

Comment: @Mike, Oracle по сути весь бесплатен, у них плата идет за техподдержку, без которой лицинзионное использование запрещено. Но вот тулзу для него стоят адско денег и реально работают недолго

Answer (score 1):

не знаю, что конкретно вы имеете под "бесплатной версией", но точно знаю, что в учебных целях вы можете использовать полную версию базы и, разумеется, вы можете поднять EM и научиться с ним работать.